# How to use Managed Identity to fetch credentials on AKS environment?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I have node(nestjs) application deploy in AKS, clusters were created using kubenet network. The node application needs to access the sql DB, we have configured managed identities, so it'll be user managed identity.
To create connection I'm using token based approached, where I get the credentials using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity package ( using DefaultAzureCredential on local and ManagedIdentityCredential on server), and with those credentials, I get the token, and then token is used in creating the DB connection. For local it worked fine, using DefaultAzureCredential and az cli with user logged in.
But on AKS it throws error as no managed identity found( when ManagedIdentityCredential used), why is that, please help to get to the solution, it has become a huge blocker?

Comment: Have you checked if aad identity is created?
kubectl get azureidentity -n $POD_IDENTITY_NAMESPACE
kubectl get azureidentitybinding -n $POD_IDENTITY_NAMESPACE

Comment: but the our azure team, said we have created clusters with kubenet, and aad-pod-identity  requires clusters to be created with CNI, and correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: They are two different things here, did you create a user managed identity or was it already created? In the namespace controlled by the azure team, they might have created aad feature pods and nmi, but not the UMI. And if you own (have admin rights) on a ns, create the aad identity using the client_id/resourceid. Thereafter on the deployment manifests include aad label

Comment: user managed identity is created,and enabled UMI in AKS cluster level, unfortunately, I do not have admin rights. I'm not  sure if aad feature pods and nmi are created though

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if aad identity is created?

```
kubectl get azureidentity -n $POD_IDENTITY_NAMESPACE
kubectl get azureidentitybinding -n $POD_IDENTITY_NAMESPACE
```

If not add it on the cluster. There should be pods in a namespace which control the traffic flow to microsoft AAD, so Node Managed Identity(nmi), and describe node reveals pods on the node which intercept the calls.

Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity#create-a-pod-identity)

Comment: There are no pod identities created